# 3d cursor on position of vertex of subdivision modifier mesh with 'adjust cage' on

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

I have a mesh with a subdivision modifier and 'adjust edit cage' on. Now I want to move the 3D cursor to one of the points on the mesh so that I can insert a new object at the location of that vertex. However when I select the point, the center of the gizmo is a bit away from it (it's at the location where it would be if 'adjust cage' were off, see left image) and consequently when I move the 3D cursor to the selection, it's put not on the vertex but a bit away. The right image below is when I turn the 'adjust edit cage' off.

So is there a way to put the cursor at the location I'm after? Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello :). Unfortunately, gizmo currently doesn't take modifiers into account. The answer by R-800 seems like a good workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to duplicate the object in Object Mode and then, for the duplicate only, apply the Subdivision Surface modifier. Then, snap the 3D Cursor to the desired vertex on this new version of the mesh. Afterwards, either hide the new version of this mesh, or, put it in a new collection so that it can be referenced at will in the future for this same purpose. You could also delete it if you know you don't need it anymore. But you now have your desired 3D Cursor position, and you still have your original mesh with a Subdivision Surface modifier that remains unapplied.

Comment: Ah I see, I thought this would be an obvious thing I had just missed how to do. Thanks.